# What causes texture corruption in libgdx when minimising a game, going to the home screen and then going back into the game?

Tags: android, libgdx, textures, scene2d

[Tablet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haLMq.png)

When I start and run my libgdx game in Android, everything is fine.  If I navigate back to the home screen and then go back into the game, I get this texture corruption.

The corrupt objects are either Label or TextButton. The ImageButton objects are fine. The problem never happens when running inside the emulator in Android Studio. It only ever happens when deployed onto a physical phone or tablet.

Does anyone recognise what this issue might be?  Thanks.

Comment: Are labels and Textbuttons(or textures) defined static?

Comment: Yes, Label or TextButton are either static or inside a static List.

Comment: Resources releasing when you minimize the game and reloading when return to the game. However static fields cannot reloading since memory adresses stay same. So usually causing textures to swapping randomly.This may be your problem

Comment: Ah, thank you Deniz.  That's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your textures as static , you must not dispose them. If the problem isn't this , I don't know why .